# Does OP_EQUALVERIFY have a return value?

Tags: script

The Bitcoin wiki has a page that summarizes [OP_EQUAL and OP_EQUALVERIFY](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Bitwise_logic):

> OP_EQUAL
>
> - Opcode (Hex): 135 (0x87)
> - Input: x1 x2
> - Output: True / false
> - Summary: Returns 1 if the inputs are exactly equal, 0 otherwise.
>
> OP_EQUALVERIFY
>
> - Opcode (Hex): 136 (0x88)
> - Input: x1 x2
> - Output: True / false
> - Summary: Same as OP_EQUAL, but runs OP_VERIFY afterward.

`OP_EQUALVERIFY` is listed as having a return code, when it doesn't seem like it should. (`OP_EQUAL OP_VERIFY` wouldn't leave anything on the stack.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the execution of OP_EQUAL gives true, then it does not leave true/false on the stack. If it is false then it leaves false on top of the stack and stops executing.

```
Bstack.push_back(fEqual ? vchTrue : vchFalse);
if (opcode == OP_EQUALVERIFY)
{
if (fEqual)
    popstack(stack);
else
    return set_error(serror, SCRIPT_ERR_EQUALVERIFY);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.10/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L634-641)

Comment: Is the Bitcoin wiki wrong on this one, then?

Comment: I would say so. I think it should be Nothing / False, just like OP_VERIFY.